# Location of Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database

I would like to know the physical location of my SQL Azure Database. It is in Location = Southeast Asia. Which country is it located in?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/geographies/

Answer (score 2):

The physical location is located in Singapore

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/global-infrastructure/geographies/#geographies

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While you create a database they are placed in same location as in its server. When creating the SQL server note the location in the region beside it. You can then navigate to [Azure geographies](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/geographies/#geographies) to find the latest  data center regions.

[image]

In your case, for Southeast Asia: Select region "Asia Pacific" and under "Southeast Asia" find the `location` tag "**Singapore**"

[image]

You can also utilize [Products available by region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?regions=asia-pacific-southeast,asia-pacific-east&products=azure-sql-database)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Under Data residency, it states "Stored at rest in the Asia Pacific region". What does that mean?

Comment: "at rest" simply means your data, sql data stored in disks (azure infra) reside in Asia Pacific region. You may move, copy, or replicate to other regions for data resiliency - then it is moved